# Component rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `Tag` component that accepts a param (a `bookid`) and retrieves related `tags` for that particular book.

```
class Tags extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state={
            tags: '',
            bookid: ''
        };
    }
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        if(prevState.bookid===this.props.bookid) {
            console.log(prevState);
            console.log(this.state);
            return;
        }

        var URI='http://api/book/tagsByBookId/'+this.props.bookid;
        console.log(URI);

        fetch(URI)
            .then(response => {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(json => {
                console.log(json);
                this.setState({
                    tags: json.out,
                    bookid: this.props.bookid

                });
            });
    }

    render() {
        let tags=this.state.tags;

        return (
            <div className="feature">
                <div className="icon">
                    <i className="glyphicons tags" />
                </div>
                <div className="text">
                    <h3>TAG</h3>
                    <small>
                        {
                            Object.keys(tags).map(function(tag,i) {


                                return (
                           <span id={"tag-"+tag} key={"tag-"+tag}><a href={"/books/list/tag/"+tags[i].tag}>{tags[i].tag}</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
                                );
                            })
                        }

                    </small>&nbsp;&nbsp;

                    <br />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

This `Tag` component will be reused in two locations: `BookDetail` component and `ReadingList` component.

In `BookDetail` component's `render` function, I put:

```
<Tags bookid={book.bookid} />
```

This works fine. The console log shows the output from `Tags.componentDidUpdate()` function.

In `ReadingList` component's `render` function, I put:

```
Object.keys(readings).map((reading, index) => {
    let book=readings[index].book;
    console.log("Reading mapping:"+book.bookid);
    return (
        <table key={"review-" + index} className="table">
             <tbody>
                  <tr>
                      <td className="col-sm-3">
                           <img src="..."/>
                      </td>
                      <td className="col-sm-3">
                           <a href="...">{book.title}</a>
                      </td>
                      <td className="col-sm-2">{book.author}</td>
                      <td className="col-sm-3">
                            <Tags key={book.bookid} bookid={book.bookid} />
                      </td>
```

...........

That is, the `Tags` component now shall be generated/rendered multiple times in a `map` loop.

The problem is: while `Tags` component is working fine in `BookDetail` (when it only get rendered once for one particular book), this `Tags` component is not working in `ReadingList`. There is no console log at all, which seems to me that `Tags.componentDidUpdate` does get called at all.

The only difference I can figure out is: `BookDetail` will only have one `Tags` but in `ReadingList` the `Tags` is invoked by a `map`.

Would appreciate your valuable input.

Comment: Is there no console log even for the one for "Reading mapping:"+book.bookid?

Comment: Could you post up the structure of yourreadingsobject?

Comment: Reading Mapping: 12345... is showing and the rest of the table is showing too. Only missing the tag part `<Tags ... />

Comment: BTW, the readings object structure is very, very long as it has nested tables.